# Data are showing in abnormal view after updating in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, treeview, parent-child, parent

I am facing an issue in my `PHP` project I have a tree view to show my data in it data show perfectly but the issue is when I update the record from the `database` lie changing parent so that child value show as a parent see the screenshot below for better understanding and help me.
This is the image where data showing wrong: [image: https://i.imgur.com/E7XmQTE.png]

This is the screenshot where you can see my data exactly it is correct:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/bMnn1Yi.png]

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'modern');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$qry = "SELECT * FROM chart_sheet";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);

//$result=mysql_query($qry);

$arrayCategories = array();


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arrayCategories[$row['chart_sheet_id']] = array("parent_id" => $row['parent_id'], "account_name" =>
        $row['account_name'], "closing_account" => $row["closing_account"], "account_no" => $row["account_no"]);
}

//createTree($arrayCategories, 0);

function createTree($array, $currentParent, $currLevel = 0, $prevLevel = -1)
{

    foreach ($array as $categoryId => $category) {

        if ($currentParent == $category['parent_id']) {

            if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) echo " <ol class='tree'> ";

            if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li> ";

            if ($currLevel > 0) {
                echo '<li> <label-2 for="subfolder2">' . $category["account_no"] . $category['account_name'] . '</label-2> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder2"/>';

            } else {
                echo '<li> <label-1 for="subfolder2">' . $category["account_no"] . $category['account_name'] . "(" . $category['closing_account'] . ")" . '</label-1> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder2"/>';
            }


            if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) {
                $prevLevel = $currLevel;
            }

            $currLevel++;

            createTree($array, $categoryId, $currLevel, $prevLevel);
            createTree($array, $categoryId, $currLevel, $prevLevel);

            $currLevel--;
        }

    }
    if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li>  </ol> ";
}
?>
    <div id="content" class="general-style1">
        <?php
    ?>
        <?php
    createTree($arrayCategories, 0); ?>
        <?php
    ?>
```

Comment: Why does your code call `createTree($array, $categoryId, $currLevel, $prevLevel)` twice in a row?

Comment: share your db so that we can check

Comment: how can i share my db do you want screenshot of my db

Comment: bro i found  this code from internet i just replace my DB and fields value i don't know why its calling twice in a row

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/jbmXVVo.png here is my DB screenshot

Comment: guys please help me

Comment: I would recommend going back to where you found the code on the internet and asking there. We really can't help you fix code that you aren't sure how/why it is working in the first place. You are going to probably read that and think I'm being condescending, and I apologize for that, but this is the same as I would tell anyone that I work with.

Comment: please help me bro please i am new in php

Comment: dear please see i have pasted my code here that code am using in my script